# How to delete all lines containing more than three characters in the second column of a CSV file?

Tags: bash

How can I delete all of the lines in a CSV file which contain more than 3 characters in the second column? E.g.:

```
cave,ape,1
tree,monkey,2
```

The second line contains more than 3 characters in the second column, so it will be deleted.

Comment: Yes, the data is Unicode. It has symbols from various languages.

Comment: you should specify that in your requirement, because most of these utilities do not support unicode (grep, sed. .... etc). They only do single byte character sets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
awk -F, 'length($2)<=3' input.txt
```

Comment: I tested this, and it handles escaped commas. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command:

```
grep -vE "^[^,]+,[^,]{4,}," test.csv > filtered.csv
```

Breakdown of the grep syntax:

```
-v = remove lines matching
-E = extended regular expression syntax (also -P is perl syntax)
```

bash stuff:

```
> filename = overwrite/create a file and fill it with the standard out
```

Breakdown of the regex syntax:

```
"^[^,]+,[^,]{4,},"

^ = beginning of line
[^,] = anything except commas
[^,]+ = 1 or more of anything except commas
, = comma
[^,]{4,} = 4 or more of anything except commas
```

And please note that the above is simplified and would not work if the first 2 columns contained commas in the data. (it does not know the difference between escaped commas and raw ones)

Comment: +1, but it doesn't work properly if the first field is empty.

Answer (score 2):

No one has supplied a `sed` answer yet, so here it is:

```
sed -e '/^[^,]*,[^,]\{4\}/d' animal.csv
```

And here's some test data.

```
>animal.csv cat <<'.'      
cave,ape,0
,cat,1
,orangutan,2
large,wolf,3
,dog,4,happy
tree,monkey,5,sad
.
```

And now to test:

```
sed -i'' -e '/^[^,]*,[^,]\{4\}/d' animal.csv
cat animal.csv
```

Only ape, cat and dog should appear in the output.

Comment: This might work for the test data but not for the question in general. Perhaps `sed -e '/^[^,]*,[^,]\{4\}/d'` might be a little more *bullet-proof*?

Answer (score 2):

This is a filter script for your type of data. It assumes your data is in utf8

```
#!/bin/bash
function px {
 local a="$@"
 local i=0
 while [ $i -lt ${#a}  ]
  do
   printf \\x${a:$i:2}
   i=$(($i+2))
  done
}
(iconv -f UTF8 -t UTF16 | od -x |  cut -b 9- | xargs -n 1) |
if read utf16header
then
 px $utf16header
 cnt=0
 out=''
 st=0
 while read line
  do
   if [ "$st" -eq 1 ] ; then
     cnt=$(($cnt+1))
   fi
   if [ "$line" == "002c" ] ; then
     st=$(($st+1))
   fi
   if [ "$line" == "000a" ]
    then
     out=$out$line
     if [[ $cnt -le 3+1 ]] ; then
        px $out
     fi
     cnt=0
     out=''
     st=0
   else
    out=$out$line
   fi
  done
fi | iconv -f UTF16 -t UTF8
```